# AI Platform notebook starts, however status is always 'reconnecting'

Tags: jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

We are new to using AI Platform.  Following the documentation for creating a new notebook seems to work fine.  I am able to launch JupyterLab and navigate through examples.  However, there is no output or error/warning messages when cells in the notebook are executed (using tutorial notebooks).  The cell gets marked as * however there is nothing happening.

The status in lower left corner goes 'starting' / 'unknown' and then stays on "Reconnecting".. using Python 3 setup (using defaults for all options when creating the notebook).  I can stop and restart the kernal but same message.  I have also tried changing to the Python 2 kernal, same results.

Is this related to the lack of output/warnings, do I have one problem or two?  and how do I know what it is preventing the connection.

I try to open a terminal window and am not able to type any commands.

how do you debug something that isn't reporting errors?

Comment: What AI Platform Notebooks version (You can see this info in the Notebook Metadata or UI)? Do you have an specific Notebook image family and Notebook that you are using ? You can see this info in the Notebook Metadata

Comment: You can open Developer Console to troubleshoot as well. Are you using any special network setup such as VPC-SC?